# Install Sublime Text 2 KDE (Kubuntu-desktop)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, sublime-text-2, kubuntu

I would like to know how to install sublime text 2 in my Kubuntu VM. I used [this guide](http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/) when I was still using Unity, but I like the UI of KDE much more so I have converted. What do I need to do to get the desktop icon working in KDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .desktop files aren't unity only, they are a common standard across all desktops. In the guide you refer to they also talk about KDE4 compatibility:

```
# Only KDE 4 seems to use GenericName, so we reuse the KDE strings.
```

As Kubuntu is Ubuntu based everything else described in that guide will most certainly work, too. Once you have followed the guide, you should find Sublime Text in your menu and from there you can add it to the desktop (Somehow by right clicking).